# PHP Simple HTML DOM: How Do I Find Urls Exist In Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, simple-html-dom

PHP: i am parsing some pages using [Simple Html Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), I have done lot the work already, but stuck at a point.

How do i get url that resides in a javascript function. (Urls are random) Like this

```
<script> 
    lstImages = array();   
    lstImages.push("abc.com/123873.php");
    lstImages.push("abc.com/125673.php");
</script>
```

How am i supposed to get them? They can be random in count, some pages have 20, some 25 and so on.

Help will be appreciated, i am exhausted already working with this thing.

Sample Code:

```
require "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = file_get_html('pages.html');

$file = fopen("links.txt","w");
foreach($html->find('a') as $link) {
    echo fwrite($file,$link->href."\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the piece of HTML you are scraping?

Comment: Sure here is pastebin [Link](http://pastebin.com/tfrF3g3p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't use a DOM parser to scrape Javascript, you can do this with Regular Expressions.

Use this:

```
$html = file_get_html('pages.html');

$re = "/push\\(\"(.*)\"\\)/"; 
$str = $html;

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

$matches now contains an array with your URL's.

Comment: Amazing That Did The Trick. [Here's The Output](http://i.imgur.com/UNfKli9.png) Thanks Man.